# HTML_Table returns an incorrect output

Tags: php, pear, html-table

I'm trying to use [PEAR::HTML_Table](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Table/docs) package to generate a table from multi-dimensional array, $data.

This is a dump of $data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Office
            [1] => Canvasser
            [2] => Fundraising Hrs
            [3] => PAC/Hr no PFU
            [4] => PAC $ no PFU
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TBS1
            [1] => Vatcher, Georgia
            [2] => 29
            [3] => 8.295
            [4] => 481
        )
)
```

EDIT: The first array is the row of my THEAD tags and any additional arrays will be rows in the TBODY tags.

And this is my code:

```
$data = $worksheet->toArray('', true, false, false); // PHPExcel

// build table
$table = new HTML_Table(array('class' => 'dt'), 0, true);
$thead =& $table->getHeader();
$tbody =& $table->getBody();

// loop through rows
for ($r = 0, $lr = count($data); $r < $lr; $r++) {
    // loop through columns
    for ($c = 0, $lc = count($data[$r]); $c < $lc; $c++) {
        if ($r == 0) {
            $thead->setCellContents($r, $c, $data[$r][$c]);
        } else {
            $tbody->setCellContents($r, $c, $data[$r][$c]);
        }
    }
}

// output html
echo $table->toHtml();
```

When it outputs the HTML, it returns a table with an extra row having blank cells in the TBODY tags. I cannot seem to figure out why it is doing that. It is important for me to get the right output because I am sending this output back to a JavaScript file for further processing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the counter for the row in the tbody.

The first body cell gets coordinates `(1,0)`, but should have `(0,0)` - the row position begins at 0, not at 1. So you implicit tell `HTML_Table` to add a clear row before your first row.

To fix it, use `$r - 1` instead of `$r` in the `else` block. And learn about `foreach()`.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Your suggestion to use foreach() does make my code shorter and cleaner. Thanks!